# "WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active. Is /clock being published?" - Force Torque

Tags: gazebo, plugin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic, gazebo 7.

Trying to implement a force torque sensor model onto the end-effector of a sawyer robot. Model was successfully implemented, but plugin doesn't publish any data. I get the warning from the question title. Yes, /clock is being published because calling "rostopic echo /clock" will show the simulation clock.

warning occurs when i call "rostopic echo /right_hand_ft_sensor/ft_sensor_topic

I've found solutions where it suggests to call the following: "rosparam set use_sim_time false" and that hasn't fixed anything.

I've also seen solutions where it says to set the update_rate of the sensor to 0 in the robot.urdf. I can't try this solution because my sawyer.urdf does not contain the relevant section in the code where i would can set it the update rate to 0. the sensor package is based on xacro and i just include in the launch file of the sawyer robot.

any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286056/%22warning:-no-messages-received-and-simulated-time-is-active.-is-/clock-being-published?%22---force-torque/) by [lr101095](https://answers.ros.org/users/34104/lr101095/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2018-03-21**:
What command are you running that causes the warning message to be published?

**Comment by [lr101095](https://answers.ros.org/users/34104/lr101095/) on 2018-03-21**:
@imcmahon please see edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Hopefully) you shouldn't need to implement your own force-torque sensor for Sawyer in Gazebo. The `sawyer_gazebo` package actually simulates the torque values being experienced by each joint in the arm directly. You can see each of these torques on the topic `/robot/joint_states`. A force-torque sensor is usually used to measure the force experienced at the end effector of the robot. Part of the simulation is a handy topic that reports all of these joint torques are transformed into the endpoint frame on the `/robot/limb/right/endpoint_state` topic using the `intera_core_msgs/EndpointState` message.

The following is the RViz rendering of the effort portion of the `/robot/joint_states` topic:
[image: Sawyer RViz Torques in Gazebo]

---

Originally posted by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) with karma: 790 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lr101095](https://answers.ros.org/users/34104/lr101095/) on 2018-03-21**:
i forgot to mention that i'm implementing the ft sensor on the end-effector of sawyer. made the correction in my post.

**Comment by [imcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/499/imcmahon/) on 2018-03-21**:
Ah, I see. I would recommend looking at the endpoint_state topic I mentioned above. It should give you the same data that a FT sensor would give in the endpoint frame.